# No space left on device while copying data to server

Tags: 14.04, server, copy

This question seems to have been answered. But many of the suggest to see if inodes are available and if any filesystem is using up 100% space. 
I'll put up the results that I'm getting. For

```
df -k
```

Results are

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             8149688        0   8149688   0% /dev
tmpfs            1633924     9524   1624400   1% /run
/dev/sda1      944882068 27007380 869854416   4% /
tmpfs            8169616    80036   8089580   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            8169616        0   8169616   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            1633924      116   1633808   1% /run/user/1000
```

For

```
df -i
```

The results are showing

```
Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev            2037422    526  2036896    1% /dev
tmpfs           2042404    717  2041687    1% /run
/dev/sda1      60006400 460087 59546313    1% /
tmpfs           2042404    131  2042273    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           2042404      5  2042399    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           2042404     16  2042388    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           2042404     45  2042359    1% /run/user/1000
```

For

```
df -h
```

The reults I'm getting are

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  9.4M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda1       902G   25G  831G   3% /
tmpfs           7.8G   80M  7.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           1.6G  116K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

The problem is that you can see from the results that there is no file system that is using 100% space or its not like there are no more inodes available. But still every time I want to copy something onto data share server from my system. The same problem is not happening for the others using the server.

So How to deal with this problem ?

Comment: How are you copying this data?

Comment: How large are the files you are trying to copy and where are you coping them to ?

Comment: The files I'm trying to copy are approximately 1GB and I'm copying using file explorer.

Comment: Where did you issue the `df` commands- on your client or on the server? On the client they are meningless when copying _to_ the server! What sort of server is that (Windows/CIFS or Linux/Unix/NFS)? Maybe the server has quotas set for you?

Comment: I issued the commands on my system. The problem is I do not have admin access to the server. I am not diagnose the if the problem is with my system or with the server.